# Accessing struct fields copy the whole struct?

Tags: c#, struct

I know that passing structs as a parameter to a method, returning them, or trying to assign a struct value to a variable creates a copy of the whole struct.

Now, take a look at the hypothetical code below:

```
//Regions is an array of a struct type. Color and r/g/b are structs too.

if(Regions[0].Color.r == Regions[0].Color.g && Regions[0].Color.b != 0){
  .
  ..      
}
```

To get **r/g/b** values, what happens below the hood? Only the **r/g/b** values are copied to a memory location or the whole Regions[0] thrice?

Comment: That's simple to check with `ReferenceEquals (Regions[0], Regions[0])`

Comment: That'll return false because the copies that are made when passing as method parameters (Regions[0] will be copied twice). My question is if the copies are made even when just accessing field members (like Color and r/g/b in the example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code replicates what you're asking about:

```
void Main()
{
    var foos = new Foo[]
    {
        new Foo() { Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red },
    };

    if (foos[0].Color.R == 45 && foos[0].Color.B == 55)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("!");
    }
}

public struct Foo
{
    public System.Drawing.Color Color;
}
```

The IL produced is this:

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0001:  newarr      Foo
IL_0006:  dup         
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0008:  ldloca.s    01 
IL_000A:  initobj     Foo
IL_0010:  ldloca.s    01 
IL_0012:  call        System.Drawing.Color.get_Red
IL_0017:  stfld       Foo.Color
IL_001C:  ldloc.1     
IL_001D:  stelem      Foo
IL_0022:  stloc.0     // foos
IL_0023:  ldloc.0     // foos
IL_0024:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0025:  ldelema     Foo
IL_002A:  ldflda      Foo.Color
IL_002F:  call        System.Drawing.Color.get_R
IL_0034:  ldc.i4.s    2D 
IL_0036:  bne.un.s    IL_0057
IL_0038:  ldloc.0     // foos
IL_0039:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_003A:  ldelema     Foo
IL_003F:  ldflda      Foo.Color
IL_0044:  call        System.Drawing.Color.get_B
IL_0049:  ldc.i4.s    37 
IL_004B:  bne.un.s    IL_0057
IL_004D:  ldstr       "!"
IL_0052:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0057:  ret
```

You'll note the two lots of each of [`ldelema`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldelema%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`ldflda`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldflda%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) op codes. Both are just passing references.

So, you **don't** make two copies. Everything is passed by reference.

Comment: He stated that `Foo` is not a class but a struct.

Comment: @user3185569 - You're right. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity If inside the if statement I had var x = foos[0].Color.R; then only the R value would be copied?

Comment: @ArthurCastro - My reading of this code is that there is no copying at all of the values. It seems that everything is by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Region is an array of structs. I made a quick example to examine the generated IL:

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo[] Regions = new Foo[10];

        Regions[0] = new Foo();


        if(Regions[0].Color.R == Regions[0].Color.G && Regions[0].Color.B != 0)
        {

        }


    }
}

public struct Foo
{
    public Color Color { set; get; }
}
```

As you can see in the generated IL below `get_Color` is called 3 times and so the value of the Color is copied 3 times and retrieved.

```
  .method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  3
    .locals init (valuetype Foo[] V_0,
             valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Color V_1,
             bool V_2)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   10
    IL_0003:  newarr     Foo
    IL_0008:  stloc.0
    IL_0009:  ldloc.0
    IL_000a:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_000b:  ldelema    Foo
    IL_0010:  initobj    Foo
    IL_0016:  ldloc.0
    IL_0017:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0018:  ldelema    Foo
    IL_001d:  call       instance valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Color Foo::get_Color()
    IL_0022:  stloc.1
    IL_0023:  ldloca.s   V_1
    IL_0025:  call       instance uint8 [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Color::get_R()
    IL_002a:  ldloc.0
    IL_002b:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_002c:  ldelema    Foo
    IL_0031:  call       instance valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Color Foo::get_Color()
    IL_0036:  stloc.1
    IL_0037:  ldloca.s   V_1
    IL_0039:  call       instance uint8 [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Color::get_G()
    IL_003e:  bne.un.s   IL_0059

    IL_0040:  ldloc.0
    IL_0041:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0042:  ldelema    Foo
    IL_0047:  call       instance valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Color Foo::get_Color()
    IL_004c:  stloc.1
    IL_004d:  ldloca.s   V_1
    IL_004f:  call       instance uint8 [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Color::get_B()
    IL_0054:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0055:  ceq
    IL_0057:  br.s       IL_005a

    IL_0059:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_005a:  nop
    IL_005b:  stloc.2
    IL_005c:  ldloc.2
    IL_005d:  brtrue.s   IL_0061

    IL_005f:  nop
    IL_0060:  nop
    IL_0061:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Main
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the values of `Color` copied three times?

Comment: @Enigmativity  `Foo::get_Color()` gets a copy of that `Color` AFAIK.

Comment: @Enigmativity It makes a lot of difference if `Color` is a property (in my case) and a public Field (as in your case)